# RegEx replace for invalid Numeric character reference

Tags: c#, regex, xml

Need some serious RegEx help with replacing invalid Numeric character reference in Xml document.

Some of our Xml data used production is being made unreadable due to a known bug in [XmlWriter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2652319) by which semicolons are getting dropped when you write XML entities. Unfortunately for me for some strange reason the production environment was not running on latest .Net framework which resulted in quite a lot of these kind of data being inserted to the database, and now I have to find a fix for reading back and fixing this data somehow.

An example of misconstrued XML (in below XML look for **&#xE1d&** and **&#x3A3**):

```
<TestInvalidUnicodeReading Desc="a&#xF1;o &#x20AC;  &#x3A3 &#xC6; Jako efektivn&#x11;B;j&#x161;&#xED; se n&#xE1;m jev&#xED; po&#x159&#xE1d&#xE1;n&#xED; tzv. st&#x159ed;nictv&#xED;m na&#x161;ich an&#xFDc;h dealer&#x16F; v &#x10Cec;h&#xE1c;h a na Morav&#x11;B, kter&#xE9; prob&#x11;Bhnou v pr&#x16Fb;&#x11;Bhu z&#xE1;&#x159;&#xED; a &#x159;&#xEDjna.bddb26e234c5452aab7720c581e137f7" />
```

Now to fix this I have devised the following [RegEx solution](https://regex101.com/r/lT8zL1/2) and use it in C# to find the match and add the missing semi-colon, which works partially:

```
&((?:#([0-9]+)|#x([0-9a-fA-F]+)|([0-9a-zA-Z]+))[?&0-9a-zA-Z ])
```

Now the problem is with the **&#xE1d&** section.

[image]

Since when this above RegEx matches the previous match the next **&#xE1d&** is getting skipped. Can someone please lend me a hand finding a solution to this RegEx issue??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can improve the regex by using a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
&(#[0-9]+(?![0-9;])|#x[0-9a-fA-F]+(?![0-9a-fA-F;]))
```

will only match numeric character references that are not followed by a `;`.

**Explanation:**

```
&                 # Match &
(                 # Start of capturing group:
 #[0-9]+          # Match either # plus digits  
 (?![0-9;])       # as long as they are not followed by a semicolon or more digits
|                 #
 #x[0-9a-fA-F]+   # match #x plus hex digits
 (?![0-9a-fA-F;]) # as long as they are not followed by semicolon or hex
)                 # End of group
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/qA7dK5/3).